# case when exists in oracle update query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have update query like

```
update dedupctntest a set a.city = case when exists(
select b.shortname from DEDUPADDRESSDICT where lower(a.city) =lower(b.shortname) and rownum = 1) b  then
b.fullname else a.city end;
```

but it will give `missing keyword` error

can anybody tell what is wrong in that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference b.fullname outside its scope, which is inside the exists() clause.

Maybe this does what you need:

```
update dedupctntest a
set a.city = coalesce
              ( ( select b.fullname 
                  from DEDUPADDRESSDICT 
                  where lower(a.city) = lower(b.shortname) 
                  and rownum = 1
                )
              , a.city
              );
```

i.e. if the query from DEDUPADDRESSDICT returns a non-null fullname use that, else use a.city.  Note that if there is a row in DEDUPADDRESSDICT with a null fullname then a.city will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
update dedupctntest a set a.city = case when exists( 
select * from DEDUPADDRESSDICT where lower(a.city) =lower(b.shortname) and rownum = 1) b  then 
(select fullname form DEDUPADDRESSDICT where lower(a.city) =lower(b.shortname) and rownum = 1)
b.fullname else a.city end;
```